# Replacement for missing liquibase classes moving from liquibase 2.0.3 to 3.3.0

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a project using liquibase-core 2.0.3. When I updated to liquibase-core 3.3.0 I'm getting a lot of compiler class not found errors for the classes below.

Any help on info on where/what they have been replaced with is much appreciated?

```
import liquibase.change.core.AnonymousChange;

import liquibase.database.core.MaxDBDatabase;

import liquibase.database.typeconversion.TypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.CacheTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.DB2TypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.DefaultTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.DerbyTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.FirebirdTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.H2TypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.HsqlTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.InformixTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.MSSQLTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.MaxDBTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.MySQLTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.OracleTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.Postgres83TypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.PostgresTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.SQLiteTypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.SybaseASATypeConverter;
import liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.SybaseTypeConverter;

import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.DB2DatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.DerbyDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.H2DatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.HsqlDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.InformixDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.MSSQLDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.MySQLDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.OracleDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.PostgresDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.SQLiteDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
import liquibase.snapshot.jvm.StandardJdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator;
```

Answer (score 0):

MaxDBDatabase was pulled into a separate extension https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-maxdb so you will need to include that jar as well.

The TypeConverter code mainly moved to the classes in liquibase.datatype.

The database-specific SnapshotGenerator classes were replaced with a more general-purpose SnapshotGeneratorFactory and object-specific subclasses vs. database-specific subclasses.

I see you cross-posted to the liquibase forum at http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/replacement-for-missing-liquibase-classes-moving-from-liquibase-2-0-3-to-3-3-0#49382000001219004 If you have specific usage questions, that is probably the best place to follow up since it is more discussion-oriented than stackoverflow.